# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline - GitHub Enterprise Issues?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have spent days troubleshooting/researching this issue. I can't seem to figure out what's going on here. I'm trying to setup a multibranch pipeline project pointed at our internal GitHub enterprise servers.  The same issue occurs in other project types too like the "GitHub Organization". It's some sort of security issue that I can't figure out.

Let's start with what I know...

I have (to my knowledge) configured the GitHub Plugin configuration correctly with a TOKEN (also configured per documentation)... I can successfully "Verify Credentials" and it comes back successful. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg9Bv.jpg

**I keep getting this validation issue on the GitHub Enterprise Servers Validation**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9v27.jpg

I can connect successfully to any ONE repository hosted on my enterprise github server. When I try to configure a multi-branch project from a GitHub source, I ALWAYS get BLANK for repositories.... 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX52A.jpg

I configured a custom logger to see what was going on and it seems like the branch source plugin is always going out to api.github.com...

`Jan 25, 2016 11:48:23 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.Endpoint$DesciptorImpl doCheckApiUri
Jan 25, 2016 11:48:23 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.Endpoint$DesciptorImpl doCheckApiUri
Jan 25, 2016 11:54:58 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.AbstractGitHubSCMSource$AbstractGitHubSCMSourceDescriptor doFillRepositoryItems
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.github.com/user
Jan 25, 2016 11:54:58 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.AbstractGitHubSCMSource$AbstractGitHubSCMSourceDescriptor doFillRepositoryItems
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.github.com/orgs/nhudacin
Jan 25, 2016 11:54:58 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.AbstractGitHubSCMSource$AbstractGitHubSCMSourceDescriptor doFillRepositoryItems
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.github.com/users/nhudacin`

I've configured the API endpoint for the GitHub plugin (as seen in the first screen shot), for the PR Builder plugin and the credentials are working (or so it seems). I'm thinkin it's a probably with the enterprise API endpoint configuration.

Any help?? I'm going CRAZY here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue as [Nick H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2848488/nick-h)

In my production Jenkins instance

- Jenkins version 2.17 Latest weekly release with all plugins up to date as of Aug 10 i.e

  - GitHub Branch Source Plugin 1.8.1
  - PipelineMultibranch 2.8

I get :

```
WARNING: Server returned HTTP response code: -1, message: 'null' for URL: https://api.github.com/users/ORG
```

Even when I have configured the *API endpoint* on *GitHub Enterprise Servers* to be http://github.MYDOMAIN/api/v3/

On the other hand, on a fresh local install of Jenkins

with the same configuration I get:

```
Aug 11, 2016 3:19:14 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource$DescriptorImpl doFillRepositoryItems

WARNING: Exception retrieving the repositories of the owner ORG on  with credentials USER/****** ( test credentials)
```

---

Edit: I found a way to make it work, it was not very intuitive, I found it after browsing the code and matching the strings to the plugin UI

What you need to do is, after you get the **Invalid credentials** red error press `Advanced...` button

[image]

Then a combo box with the `API endpoints` defined in the `Manage Jenkins-> Configure System -> GitHub Enterprise Servers` will appear.

[image]

Select the API endpoint for you GitHub Enterprise instance,  choose `Checkout credentials` that have access to that instance and the list of all the repositories will appear.

Save it, and start a Branch indexing discovering the branches that have a JenkinsFile on it.

NOTE: in order to have this working every push a web hook needs to be installed in github Enterprise, you can do that by going

`Manage Jenkins-> Configure System -> GitHub`  and press the second `Advanced...` button

[image]

Now a `Re-register hook for all jobs` button will appear. Just press that and it should add the hook that will be triggered every time you push into your matching repos.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge about this particular scenario, but in [this commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-branch-source-plugin/commit/b05cadb17e87952955d25c7e91e1e03fa82758c9) you can see, that they switched from regex validation to anonymous connection to endpoint. And if your server is in `private mode`, it will fail.

Comment: Interesting.. It could be in private mode. How would I tell?

Comment: That's what I cannot tell, sadly, cause I don't have experience with gihub enreprise, only Jenkins itself :)

Comment: Over the weekend, I talked our hosted Enterprise GitHub administrator to switch off the private mode switch. I thought FOR SURE this was going to work but it didn't. It seems there is a bug somewhere in the branch source api plugin that always goes out to the public github api. Thanks for the help!